# Grayed-Out Sleep and Hibernate Options on Windows 7 After Updating Graphics Driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, display, hibernate

I have a Gateway M275 Tablet PC, on which I've installed Windows 7 Ultimate. The laptop is quite old, so there aren't any Win7 drivers for it, not to mention any Vista drivers.

Win7 has been working for some time, but I noticed that my video output wasn't working. I went into Device Manager and found that I didn't have a driver for my video card: it just recognized it as the standard one. I searched online and found an XP driver for it, released by Gateway. Device Manager accepted this driver and prompted me to reboot.

After that, I noticed that **my Sleep and Hibernate options in the Shut Down menu have been grayed-out**. I looked online and found that many people are attributing this to display drivers, as such an old driver would surely not be compatible with the standby procedures Windows 7 uses.

To make it clear: I was able to Sleep and Hibernate before updating the drivers; now, I can't. Running `powercfg /a` gives me, "An internal system component has disabled this standby state," for each available standby mode.

Is there **some way that the driver can be modified to support hibernation**? The new driver fixed my video output problem, but I guess hibernation is more important for me.

If not, what **steps should I take to remove the driver and just leave the standard Windows one**, which previously supported hibernation and sleep on this computer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Tablet use an Intel chipset MB?  Intel could have a chipset driver/inf package that supports WIN 7.  Check under Device Manager/System Devices and the manual may say as well.  A spec I found lists Intel 85822GME and it has Intel NIC.  Not a sure indication of Intel MB but worth checking.  The INF update has assisted in may issues I have encountered in the past.

Just be sure to have a good backup.

Answer (score 1):

Use device manager to roll back the driver

this is for XP, but very similar for W7
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/driverrollback.mspx

Screenshots of W7 device manager
http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/515982-how-use-device-manager-windows-7-a.html

.